# Handling numerous micro dependencies

Tags: algorithm, oop, design-patterns

I have a service that handles different client types. There are a lot of service classes that differ in minute ways in the way they process different clients. For the most part these classes contain logic that is common to all clients, however there are places with logic specific to clients.

I understand I could use a Factory to return a set of objects for client specific logic, or use the Template method to have concrete implementations of an abstract class for different clients -- the problem with these approaches is that there are a lot of minute branching decisions that have to be made based on the client throughout the code, and these minute branching decisions are trivial, unconnected to each other, and they don't warrant separate classes. Is there a design pattern to elegantly implement this?

```
class Service {

   void process() {
     //....
     if (client1) doStuff1();
     if (client2) doStuff2();
     //....
     if (client1) name = "xyz";
     else if (client2) name = "abc";
     //....
     if (client1) sortasc();
     else  sortdesc();
     //....
     if (client2) processx();
     else if (client3) processy();
   }

}
```

Comment: How about the composite design pattern? en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: In OOP, just about anything warrants separate classes. If it's a business rule, make it a class. Don't hesitate to create more classes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are falling into a common trap.  The service implementation is *mostly* the same for every, so you want to write the 'common' implementation and then code client-specific extensions.  Each time you need to do something special for a client, though, you end up modifying the common service implementation, which quickly becomes an unmaintainable mess.

But really, there is no rule that the implementation *has* to be the same for every client.  If there was such a rule, then you wouldn't have so many exceptions.  The truth is that the processing is *different* for every client, and they just happen to be mostly the same *today*.

You should make a separate service implementation for each type of client.

If you are now starting to say "but I don't want to duplicate all the common code!", then stop.  Take parts that really are common and extract them into utility methods that the different client implementations can call.   The amount of code shared is pretty much the same...

```
class Client1Service implements Service {
    void process() {
        doCommonSetup();
        doStuff1();
        doCommonThing();
        doStuffWithName("xyz");
        sortasc();
        doMoreCommonStuff();
        processy();
    }
}
```

... but now there's no mess of conditions, and when you need to make client-specific changes, there is a place to do that that doesn't mess up the implementations for all the other clients.

When you need to make changes to the common parts, well, there is also a single implementation of that stuff that you can modify.